# AJAX Call, it returns NOT Acceptable using SPRING MVC Hibernate

Tags: ajax, spring, hibernate

I'm using Spring MVC Hibernate, I'm retrieving districts and blocks from the database. District is successfully displayed but when it comes to Blocks i'm not able to display them, what can be the problem?? please help

```js
$(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#districtcode').change(function()
            {
            
                $.ajax({         
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "./districtenrollment.htm",
                    data: "categoryCode="+ this.value,   
                        
                    success : function (data){
                    
                        $('#blockcode').empty();                            
                        $('#blockcode').append($("<option>").val("-1").text("Select"));                
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            $('#blockcode').append($("<option>").val(data[i][1]).text(data[i][0])); 
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert("error:" + textStatus + " - exception:" + errorThrown);         
                    }
                });  
                    
            });
        });
```

```html
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="disblo" autocomplete="off" >
            <h3 id="heading"><u>Please Select</u></h3>
            <table id="tab">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        User Id:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form:input path="myid"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        User name:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form:input path="username"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Select District</td>
                    <td> 
                        <form:select path="mDistricts.districtcode" id="districtcode">                         
                            <form:option value="-1">Select </form:option>
                            <c:forEach var="c" items="${districtlist}">                                     
                                <form:option value="${c.districtcode}" >${c.districtname}
                                </form:option>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </form:select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Select Block</td>
                    <td> 
                        <form:select path="mBlocks.blockcode" id="blockcode">                         
                            <form:option value="-1">Select </form:option>
                            <c:forEach var="c" items="${blocklist}">                                     
                                <form:option value="${c.blockcode}" >${c.blockname}
                                </form:option>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </form:select>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </form:form>
```

`

This is my controller

```
@Autowired
    private D_BDAO d_bdao;

    @RequestMapping(value="Dist_Block.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getmodel(@ModelAttribute("disblo") usertestDisBlock db, HttpSession session) {
         List<MDistricts> districtlist = d_bdao.getAllCategory();
        org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView model = new org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView("Dist_Block");
        model.addObject("districtlist", districtlist);
        System.out.println("after model");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/districtenrollment.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    List<MBlocks> getmodel1(@RequestParam("categoryCode") Integer categoryCode) {
        System.out.println("categoryCode="+categoryCode);
        List<MBlocks> blocklist;
        System.out.println("i'm here in ajax controller ");
        blocklist = d_bdao.getAllBlocks(categoryCode);
        System.out.println("i'm here after b_dao ");
        System.out.println("c " + blocklist);
        return blocklist;
    }
```

This is my DAO Implementation

```
 @Override
    public List<MDistricts> getAllCategory() {
        org.hibernate.Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        String hql = "from MDistricts";
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        List<MDistricts> districtlist = query.list();
        session.close();
        return districtlist;
    }

     @Override
    public List<MBlocks> getAllBlocks(Integer districtcode) {
        org.hibernate.Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        SQLQuery q = session.createSQLQuery("select blockname, blockcode from test_schema.m_blocks where districtcode=:districtcode ORDER BY blockname");
        q.setParameter("districtcode", districtcode);
        List<MBlocks> blocklist = q.list();
        session.close();
        System.out.println("blocklist" + blocklist);
        return blocklist;
    }
```

Comment: yes i've re-edit my post. thanks in advance v.ladynev

Comment: thanks Usman Maqbool

Comment: Somebody please help me

Answer (score 0):

I am not a telepath. But I can make an assumption (cause you don't provide enough information: stacktrace of the error, entity classes).

This code is incorrect

```
SQLQuery q = session.createSQLQuery("select blockname, blockcode from test_schema.m_blocks where districtcode=:districtcode ORDER BY blockname");
q.setParameter("districtcode", districtcode);
List<MBlocks> blocklist = q.list();
```

`session.createSQLQuery()` doesn't return `List<MBlocks>`, but `List<Object[]>`. Try this code with HQL:

```
Query q = session.createQuery(
    "from MBlocks where districtcode = :districtcode order by blockname");
q.setParameter("districtcode", districtcode);
List<MBlocks> blocklist = q.list();
```

And try to log errors.

Comment: @Boss.H You are welcome. So have you solved it using my answer?

Comment: No, it was my Problem, JQuery and Jar Files like json-simple and json-all did the work for me, the problem was in the mapping. But i want to thank you for your support, Keep it up :) Do you want me to send you the solved problem??  if yes, please give me your email-id

Comment: @Boss.H You can add your own answer here and accept it :)